# What implications does the outer automorphism of $S_6$ have in the algebra of rational, real, or complex numbers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, soft-question, symmetric-groups, automorphism-group

I know that the group $S_6$ has an outer automorphism. I also know that group theory, specifically the simplicity of $A_5$, implies that quintics are unsolvable. Does the outer automorphism of $S_6$ have easy-to-state consequences in the algebra of rational, real, or complex numbers, like the statement "general quintics are unsolvable"?

Comment: Yes, see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2855524/hölders-theorem-group-theory-proof-collection-and-applications).